Two women, "Muses?" begin to look after a man
Every man's fantasy? 
Two women move into this man's house and seem to have a specific task to mind him, care for him maybe even protect him.  They treat him as if he's very important.  The man has no idea why but seems to bless his good fortune.  They work to keep him, do the shopping, look after the house and have sex with him.  
In one scene he has sex with one of the women for the first time and feels guilty as if he's cheated on the other when she returns.  He starts to apologise and explain but she isn't at all bothered and placates him.  It's as if it's perfectly acceptable to do this.  You get the feeling that the women are there specifically to care for / protect / mind him because he has some purpose and that they are something like "Muses".  I can't remember if there is a supernatural/fantasy element to why they are doing this.

This reminds me of a German film I saw many years ago.
The Philosopher / Der Philosoph from 1988 or 1989 depending on who you believe.
In this film there are 3 women and he moves in with them. They are described as "Graces" rather than "Muses".
imdb
wikipedia (in German)

Thank you.  On further checking this is the very movie I was enquiring about.  Not sure how to upvote you yet.
